# I am perplexed by this script. I believe it is Chinese, be appreciative if it could translate into English and/or give further meaning. att image

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, character-identification, traditional-characters, culture

Old ink painting with characters that I would like to understand and be translated. I have various ink paintings with plants, animals and humans but have never understood the meaning of the characters. Thx[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is an old limerick (打油詩) that advise people to not smoke opium (鴉片)

From right to left:

當初有錢食舊公 - Way before when I had money I dined with old friends

許多煙屎朋友到 - Many opium-smoking friends came

枕上說談靝下事 - laid on pillows we talked about current affairs

壹杵吹散古今愁 - With a pipe, we blew away all the worries along with the smoke

嘮到極地賣田屋 - Smoke so much that at the end I had to sell my field and house

傢伙什物妻婆兒 - Along with my belongings, wife, and children

女過別人家艱難 - Daughter went to other people's home and suffer

有誰可連食三硃 - Who could take three hits one after another?

煙屎師爺無精神 - opium addictive people have no energy

介(戒)之則吉好利市 - Stop smoking opium is the best thing to do, and you will profit in every aspect

都日(是?)良言 - All good advice

In the late Qing Dynasty, opium addiction was a huge social problem. Since many people can't read, Anti-drug groups would use limerick (打油詩) to advise the public, 打油诗 could be memorized like a song and it can spread more easily

Comment: The unidentified character is 靝 tian1, which is a rare variant of 天

Comment: Thanks, I just didn't know how to input it

Comment: Not to mention the cause of the Opium Wars which changed the history of China forever.